# XSL counting specific nodes only within a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to setup a xslt file that reads from xml file which contains a number of `<student>` tags and inside each student they can have multiple `<course>` tags which contain course information.

The xslt file reads a loop of each student prints it out in a table, but I'm having trouble trying to do a count of the number of courses each student has but all it does when you do

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//student/course)" />
```

it lists every students course for a total of 21. I want it to try and just have this student has 2 courses and then when I print out the next student it lists how many courses that student has eg. 3, etc. Any idea how to setup the count so it only does each student only its courses and not all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a multitude of ways to achieve this. A little more code would help narrow down the context, but we can get around that. What I'd suggest is instead of `count(//student/course)` call an apply templates, then pick-up each student element and output the `count(course)` like so where you have your current code:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

and add this template to output the counts

```
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(course)" />
</xsl:template>
```

That should do it. Oh you can test it out online here:

http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/TF0Yji

Comment: Thanks, I added the <xsl:value-of select="count(course)" /> tag to my XSLT file and it worked perfectly, adding the courses in each student individually rather than all courses for all students. Knew it would be something simple once someone pointed it out. Cheers again

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<student>
 <course>two</course>
 <course>three</course>
</student>
<student>
 <course>ten</course>
 <course>nine</course>
 <course>six</course>
</student>
</list>
```

and apply this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:param name="pos">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:param>
    
    <number>
    <xsl:text>Student number </xsl:text>  
     <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
    <xsl:text> has </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(course)"/>
     <xsl:text> courses.</xsl:text>
    </number>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
 <number>Student number 1 has 2 courses.</number>
 <number>Student number 2 has 3 courses.</number>
</list>
```